JSDoc source links are incorrect
I'm using jsdoc and better-docs to document my typescript code. I encounter two not that fatal but very annoying problems. One of them is connected to the source links. On everything I have documented I have a button "View source" and a link next to it that should point to the specific line in the code where the thing that's documented is defined.
The links in question
The latter however does not lead me there - it either shows me the code form the beginning and not from that specified line or the line number is wrong overall by a huge margin.
For example I have a Section class component in my code that I have documented and a public method render() in it. The generated link to the specific line where the method is defined is line 160 but I don't even have 160 lines of code in the ts file. I have only 151 lines and the method is on line 108. Here is my jsdoc.json for reference:
{
    "source": {
        "include": [
            "packages/components"
        ],
        "includePattern": ".+\\.ts$",
        "exclude": [
            "packages/components/DataProjection/node_modules",
            "packages/libs/Popper/node_modules",
            "packages/libs/Charts/node_modules"
        ],
        "excludePattern": "(^|\\/|\\\\)_."
    },
    "plugins": [
        "node_modules/better-docs/typescript",
        "node_modules/better-docs/category"
    ],
    "opts": {
        "destination": "./docs/",
        "recurse": true,
        "template": "node_modules/better-docs",
        "readme": "README.md",
        "verbose": true
    },
    "templates": {
        "cleverLinks": false,
        "monospaceLinks": false,
        "search": true,
        "default": {
            "outputSourceFiles": true
        },
        "better-docs": {
            "name": "VELOCITY-UI",
            "title": "VELOCITY-UI",
            "hideGenerator": true
        },
        "staticFiles": {
            "include": [
                "./static"
            ]
        }
    }
}

I couldn't find any documentation on how the source links are generated so I'm hoping to receive an answer here.
